# Change link unfurling image used by Notion

Tags: slack, links, images

Whenever you post a link to Notion into Slack etc, the image that unfurls is always this: [image: Notion default image for link unfurling]

Is it possible to change the image used in Notion for link unfurling? Ideally it would either be the image selected for the page cover, or the first image in the page.

Tech stuff - in the Notion html `head`, this is what needs to change `<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.notion.so/images/meta/default.png">`.

Answer (score 1):

While this is not something that already exists AFAIK, one can make an app that listens for URLs from notion.so, and calls [chat.unfurl](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.unfurl) API with the relevant images/blocks in response.

Slack lists a [sample application](https://github.com/slackapi/sample-app-unfurls) on their github that works for flicker URLs.